# React native error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'prod.title')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting this error when I try to run this code. I have set the products variable as well. Can I know why this error occurs?

```
<View style={styles.prodCont}>
  <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
    <FlatList
      data={products}
      renderItem={({prod}) => (
        <ProductCard 
          cardType="social"
          title={prod.title}
          imageUrl={prod.imageUrl}
          price={prod.price}
          unit={prod.unit}
          overallRating={prod.overallRating}
          likes={prod.likes}
          userID={route.params.userEmail} 
        />
       )}
       keyExtractor={(prod,index) => {
         return prod._id
       }}
     />
   </ScrollView>
 </View>
```

Comment: If it says it's undefined, it's almost certainly undefined. Is `products` retrieved asynchronously? If so, are you handing the render before the async process has completed?

Comment: yes products are fetched before rendering . And thank you so much for the advice ill check again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function renderItem of FlatList passes a parameter with an item attribute, representing an item in the list, and also I believe you don't need the ScrollView with FlatList, as FlatList has the horizontal attribute, try switching to this code:

```
<View style={styles.prodCont}>
 <FlatList
 horizontal
 data={products}
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ProductCard 
      cardType="social"  
      title={item.title} 
      imageUrl={item.imageUrl} 
      price={item.price} 
      unit={item.unit} 
      overallRating={item.overallRating} 
      likes={item.likes} 
      userID={route.params.userEmail} 
    />
 )}
 keyExtractor={(prod,index) => prod._id}
 />
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but the cards are displaying horizontally without any space in between is there a way to change that

Comment: You can use FlatList's ItemSeparatorComponent property, it takes a function that returns a JSX element, which can behave as a spacer between items.

Answer (score 0):

The object passed to the `renderItem` function has the following properties:

```
renderItem({
  item: ItemT,
  index: number,
  separators: {
    highlight: () => void;
    unhighlight: () => void;
    updateProps: (select: 'leading' | 'trailing', newProps: any) => void;
  }
}): JSX.Element;
```

In other words, the product is in the `item` property. Your current code attempts to destructure a property named `prod`, which doesn't exist.

[FlatList renderItem property docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem)

---

*Unrelated*

IMO the `ProductCard` usage should look closer to this:

```
<ProductCard 
  cardType="social"
  product={item}
  userID={route.params.userEmail} 
/>
```

There's no (good) reason to force passing each product property separately. You could allow **optional** properties in case you want to override the values in the product itself, though.